# Create a list with named values by applying a function to each row of a data frame

Tags: r

I'm trying to get a list where each element has a name, by applying a function to each row of a data frame, but can't get the right output.

Assuming this is the function that I want to apply to each row:

```
format_setup_name <- function(m, v, s) {
 a <- list()
 a[[paste(m, "machines and", v, s, "GB volumes")]] <- paste(num_machines,num_volumes,vol_size,sep="-")
 a
}
```

If this is the input data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(m=c(1,2,3), v=c(3,3,3), s=c(15,20,30))
```

I can't get a list that looks like:

```
$`1-3-15`
[1] "1 machines and 3 15 GB volumes"

$`2-3-20`
[1] "2 machines and 3 20 GB volumes"

$`3-3-30`
[1] "3 machines and 3 30 GB volumes"
```

Can someone give me hints how to do it?

Why do I need this? Well, I want to populate `selectizeInput` in shiny using values coming from the database. Since I'm combining several columns, I need a way to match the selected input with the values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a good use case for `setNames` which can add the `names()` attribute to an object, in place. Also, if you use `as.list`, you can do this in just one line without any looping:

```
setNames(as.list(paste(df$m, ifelse(df$m == 1, "machine", "machines"), "and", df$v, df$s, "GB volumes")), paste(df$m,df$v,df$s,sep="-"))
# $`1-3-15`
# [1] "1 machine and 3 15 GB volumes"
# 
# $`2-3-20`
# [1] "2 machines and 3 20 GB volumes"
# 
# $`3-3-30`
# [1] "3 machines and 3 30 GB volumes"
```

Comment: Thanks, this works nicely. How could I add an `ifelse` to the story, so I could have in `paste` something like: `paste(m, ifelse(m==1,"machine","machines"), ...`?

Comment: Pretty much just like that, actually. Just replace the current "machines" with that ifelse statement.

Comment: I was seeing an error when doing exactly that (something as ' argument "nm" is missing, with no default'), but realized it was due to misplaced parens. Now it works like a charm, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Thomas has already found a pretty neat solution to your problem (and in one line, too!). But I'll just show you how you could have succeeded with the approach you first tried:

```
# We'll use the same data, this time called "dat" (I avoid calling 
# objects `df` because `df` is also a function's name)
dat <- data.frame(m = c(1,2,3), v = c(3,3,3), s = c(15,20,30))

format_setup_name <- function(m, v, s) {
    a <- list() # initialize the list, all is well up to here

    # But here we'll need a loop to assign in turn each element to the list
    for(i in seq_along(m)) {
        a[[paste(m[i], v[i], s[i], sep="-")]] <- 
                   paste(m[i], "machines and", v[i], s[i], "GB volumes")
    }
    return(a)
}
```

Note that what goes inside the brackets is the name of the element, while what's at the right side of the `<-` is the content to be assigned, not the inverse as your code was suggesting.

So let's try it:

```
my.setup <- format_setup_name(dat$m, dat$v, dat$s)

my.setup

# $`1-3-15`
# [1] "1 machines and 3 15 GB volumes"
#
# $`2-3-20`
# [1] "2 machines and 3 20 GB volumes"
#
# $`3-3-30`
# [1] "3 machines and 3 30 GB volumes"
```

Everything seems nice. Just one thing to note: with the `$` operator, you'll need to use single or double quotes to access individual items by their names:

```
my.setup$"1-3-15" # my.setup$1-3-15 won't work
# [1] "1 machines and 3 15 GB volumes"

my.setup[['1-3-15']] # equivalent
# [1] "1 machines and 3 15 GB volumes"
```

---

**Edit: lapply version**

Since loops have really fallen out of favor, here's a version with lapply:

```
format_setup_name <- function(m, v, s) {
    a <- lapply(seq_along(m), function(i) paste(m[i], "machines and", v[i], s[i], "GB volumes"))
    names(a) <- paste(m, v, s, sep="-")
    return(a)
}
```

Comment: Kudos for the pedagogical effort there!

Comment: Thanks @Dominic, this is really helpful. Is there a way to start from the same point, but use `apply` or any of its variants?