# argument "nm" is missing error while gathering data frames into a list by name

Tags: r, list, dataframe, lapply

I tried using the advice given in [Put multiple data frames into list (smart way)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14954399/put-multiple-data-frames-into-list-smart-way) but continue getting the following error:

```
argument "nm" is missing, with no default
```

I'm not sure why this is the case. I tried searching the error but couldn't find anything on it ([Create a list with named values by applying a function to each row of a data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29501176/create-a-list-with-named-values-by-applying-a-function-to-each-row-of-a-data-fra) shows this error in a comment but didn't explain it).

I have the following data.frames (data doesn't matter only name here):

```
#create data.frames
p1sfdf1=data.frame(a=(1:10),b=(2:11),c=(3:12))
p2sfdf1=data.frame(a=(1:10),b=(2:11),c=(3:12))
p1sfdf2=data.frame(a=(1:10),b=(2:11),c=(3:12))
p2sfdf2=data.frame(a=(1:10),b=(2:11),c=(3:12))
p1sfdf3=data.frame(a=(1:10),b=(2:11),c=(3:12))
p2sfdf3=data.frame(a=(1:10),b=(2:11),c=(3:12))
p1sfdf4=data.frame(a=(1:10),b=(2:11),c=(3:12))
#note no p2sfdf4 here
p1sfdf5=data.frame(a=(1:10),b=(2:11),c=(3:12))
p2sfdf5=data.frame(a=(1:10),b=(2:11),c=(3:12))

#combine data.frames into a list of data.frames
l.sf=setNames(lapply(ls(pattern="p[1-2]+"),function(x) get(x)))
```

I would like to group the data.frames into a list of data.frames. I tried to group based off of the pattern "p" and then either 1 or 2 but I wasn't sure how to demonstrate that in the pattern. I'm guessing that's where my error comes from, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: You can use `mget` to create a list: `mget(ls(pattern = "^p\\dsfdf\\d$"))` Not sure what you mean by "group the data.frames" - can you post the expected output?

Comment: It looks like a list for objects starting with `p1` is wanted and the another with objects `p2` to finally join all lists in one list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't passing any names to `setNames`:

```r
l.sf <- lapply(ls(pattern="p[1-2]+") ,function(x) get(x))
l.sf <- setNames(l.sf, ls(pattern="p[1-2]+"))

str(l.sf)
#> List of 9
#>  $ p1sfdf1:'data.frame': 10 obs. of  3 variables:
#>   ..$ a: int [1:10] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
#>   ..$ b: int [1:10] 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11
#>   ..$ c: int [1:10] 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
#>  $ p1sfdf2:'data.frame': 10 obs. of  3 variables:
#>   ..$ a: int [1:10] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
#>   ..$ b: int [1:10] 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11
#>   ..$ c: int [1:10] 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
#>  $ p1sfdf3:'data.frame': 10 obs. of  3 variables:
#>   ..$ a: int [1:10] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
#>   ..$ b: int [1:10] 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11
#>   ..$ c: int [1:10] 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
#>  $ p1sfdf4:'data.frame': 10 obs. of  3 variables:
#>   ..$ a: int [1:10] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
#>   ..$ b: int [1:10] 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11
#>   ..$ c: int [1:10] 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
#>  $ p1sfdf5:'data.frame': 10 obs. of  3 variables:
#>   ..$ a: int [1:10] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
#>   ..$ b: int [1:10] 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11
#>   ..$ c: int [1:10] 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
#>  $ p2sfdf1:'data.frame': 10 obs. of  3 variables:
#>   ..$ a: int [1:10] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
#>   ..$ b: int [1:10] 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11
#>   ..$ c: int [1:10] 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
#>  $ p2sfdf2:'data.frame': 10 obs. of  3 variables:
#>   ..$ a: int [1:10] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
#>   ..$ b: int [1:10] 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11
#>   ..$ c: int [1:10] 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
#>  $ p2sfdf3:'data.frame': 10 obs. of  3 variables:
#>   ..$ a: int [1:10] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
#>   ..$ b: int [1:10] 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11
#>   ..$ c: int [1:10] 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
#>  $ p2sfdf5:'data.frame': 10 obs. of  3 variables:
#>   ..$ a: int [1:10] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
#>   ..$ b: int [1:10] 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11
#>   ..$ c: int [1:10] 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

We can simply get a `name`d `list` with `mget`

```
lst1 <- mget(ls(pattern = "^p[1-2]+")
```